# there is any way to save my shared preferences data into sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

problem : i wanted to save my shared preferences data into sqLite database permanently.i here provides my code which store my data into shared preferences folder but when i am trying to store new data the previous one destroy .............is there is any solution to save the data permanently into table .........thanks in advance

```
public class CustomerWorkOrder extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText  etname ,etphone,etvname,etvno,etsdate,etldate,etremarks,etamount;
Button save,Load;
SharedPreferences SomeData;
TextView tv;
public static String filename="MySharedString";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_work_order);
    save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Load=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    etname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1name);
    etphone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2pnum);
    etvno=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3vvno);
etvname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4vvname);
etsdate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6sdate);
etldate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5ldts);
etamount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7amnt);
etremarks=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8remk);

    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    Load.setOnClickListener(this);
    SomeData=getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        String stringData=etname.getText().toString();
        String stringData1=etphone.getText().toString();
        String stringData2=etvno.getText().toString();
        String stringData3=etvname.getText().toString();
        String stringData4=etsdate.getText().toString();
        String stringData5=etldate.getText().toString();
        String stringData6=etamount.getText().toString();
        String stringData7=etremarks.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=SomeData.edit();
        editor.putString("SharedString", stringData);
        editor.putString("SharedString1", stringData1);
        editor.putString("SharedString2", stringData2);
        editor.putString("SharedString3", stringData3);
        editor.putString("SharedString4", stringData4);
        editor.putString("SharedString5", stringData5);
        editor.putString("SharedString6", stringData6);
        editor.putString("SharedString7", stringData7);
        editor.commit();
        etname.setText("");

        etphone.setText("");
        etvno.setText("");
        etvname.setText("");
        etsdate.setText("");
        etldate.setText("");
        etamount.setText("");
        etremarks.setText("");

    break;

    case R.id.button2:
        SomeData=getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        String dataReturned=SomeData.getString("SharedString", "could not load the data");
        String dataReturned1=SomeData.getString("SharedString1", "could not load the data");
        String dataReturned2=SomeData.getString("SharedString2", "could not load the data");
        String dataReturned3=SomeData.getString("SharedString3", "could not load the data");
        String dataReturned4=SomeData.getString("SharedString4", "could not load the data");
        String dataReturned5=SomeData.getString("SharedString5", "could not load the data");
        String dataReturned6=SomeData.getString("SharedString6", "could not load the data");
        String dataReturned7=SomeData.getString("SharedString7", "could not load the data");
        etname.setText(dataReturned);
        etphone.setText(dataReturned1);
        etvno.setText(dataReturned2);
        etvname.setText(dataReturned3);
        etsdate.setText(dataReturned4);
        etldate.setText(dataReturned5);
        etamount.setText(dataReturned6);
        etremarks.setText(dataReturned7);
        break;


}
```

}}

Comment: WHat do you mean that the previous one is destroyed.  Do you mean its overwritten with the new data?  That's expected.  And you'd get the same behavior with a db, unless you're very careful with your schema.  I think you need to explain what's happening and what you want a bit better.

Comment: According to sharedpreference normal behavior, it will overwrite the data(means destroyed previous one). SO, if you want to save the new data alog with previous one, why you are trying with SharedPreference? Can you work with SQlite directly?

Comment: no i dont know at present to use sqlite directly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this excellent tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) will get you started quick with SQLite.